# How can I upload a website with GitHub.io?

Tags: github

I know we are allowed a .github.io domain, but how can I upload my website there?

I have made a website with HTML/CSS/Jquery/Bootstrap... in the WebStorm IDE by Jetbrains, but I am unable to upload this to github properly? How can I upload my website properly?  The website has external images and everything else too. How does this work? [img of files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWPx7.png)

Answer (score 0):

You "upload" it in a git repository on github. It's all detailed on https://pages.github.com/

Answer (score 0):

On GitHub, you need to make a new branch called **gh-pages**. This will make a page for your project if you navigate to *yourusername.github.io/project*

You'll have to go to the **Settings** of that Repository to activate your Project's Page. GitHub will also confirm the Project's webpage address.

[This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYhgJ.jpg)

https://pages.github.com documents the process for using the *yourusername.github.io domain*

**EDIT: You don't need to make a new branch!** You'll still need to go to Settings and setup GitHub pages from there.